# Finding an explicit homeomorphism between 2x2 matrices

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I need to find a conjugacy between these matrices.  I first checked that they are similar (characteristic polynomial is same) and I get +-2i as eigenvalues.  But our book does not go over a process of actually finding this conjugacy.  The fact that the eigenvectors/eigenvalues are complex just makes me more confused.

I know the eigenvectors for both matrices and thus can find the matrix that will break each A, B down to canonical form, I'm just stuck from there.

Conceptually, I know that we can find a conjugacy from one canonical form to another, and then apply the transformation matrices from A, B back to this conjugacy to get the final answer, but I don't know the actual computations/rules.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "conjugacy" ? Usually, conjugacy and similarity are the same thing

Comment: we need to find the conjugacy, a homeomorphism between A and B.